# shorten if conditions in js

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to shorten the conditions of a javascript if but I don't know how I can achieve it

code:

```
    if ((!emailValidation() || (!nameValidation()) || (!surnameValidation()) || (!addressValidation()) || (!cityValidation()) || (!postalCodeValidation()))) {        
}
```

I have the conditions defined in this way:

```
let surnameValidation = () => {
    if (apellidoUsuario.value.length == 0) {
        surnameError();
        return false;
    }

    else if (apellidoUsuario.value.length == 1) {
        surnameError();
        return false;
    }

    else {
        apellidoUsuario.focus;
        apellidoUsuario.style.border = '0';
        apellidoUsuario.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        apellidoUsuario.style.outline = '1px solid #00ffb1'
        apellidoUsuario.style.transitionDuration = '0.4s'
        return true;
    }
```

I appreciate any help! :)

Comment: btw, after return in condition, you need no else part.

Comment: firstly you don't need to wrap all the function calls in `(`, `)`

Comment: Perhaps [deMorgan's Law](https://www.cuemath.com/data/de-morgans-law/) could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all unnecessary parenthesis in your `if` condition:

```
if (
    !emailValidation() ||
    !nameValidation() ||
    !surnameValidation() ||
    !addressValidation() ||
    !cityValidation() ||
    !postalCodeValidation()
) {
}
```

Other than that, there's not really a clean, readable way to shorten your code.

Answer (score 0):

Proposition #1:

I would probably get those validations into a variable or function:

```
validations() {
   return [
     emailValidation(),
     nameValidation(),
     surnameValidation(),
     addressValidation(),
     cityValidation(),
     postalCodeValidation()];
}
```

and then I would:

```
if(validations().some(x=> !x)){
 ...
}
```

since validations return an array you can just use the some operator to find any invalid value.

Proposition #2:

I particularly would:

```
valid() {
   return [
     emailValidation(),
     nameValidation(),
     surnameValidation(),
     addressValidation(),
     cityValidation(),
     postalCodeValidation()].every(x => x === true);
}
```

and then I would:

```
if(!valid()){
 ...
}
```

It is always cleaner to use true conditions on if statements instead of false ones.

References: Clean Code - Uncle Bob.

Comment: By shortening that `if` condition, you just increased the length of the file, and made it more difficult to see what is being checked in the `if` :D

Comment: yes, I have them inside an onclick function. it is simply to check a form, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: `[...].every();` -> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: @Cerbrus I have to agree to disagree. Good programers write code to people understand, not to computers. That extra increase will all be dismissed on bundling and even would make easier other programers to read it in source control. Also compilers would probably make the same output of both codes.

Comment: @Thomas sorry about that. It should be "valid().every(x=> x)". I have just edited the answer.

Comment: Compiler output is irrelevant when discussing readability. If you want to check what that `if` condition validates, you now have to navigate to the contents of the function.

Comment: @Cerbrus true. This is a matter of code standards so I would say that both if us are right and/or wrong depending on the perspective :)